# RoR Can't edit style until config.assets.debug = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am using an RoR opensource application, and I want to make some minor changes in it.
Like adding the possibility to use table in CKEDITOR, or embedded an other application to it.

I achieve doing all of this, but I can only see my changes, or style the embedded application if I set `config.assets.debug = true` in my environments file.

The problem is, when I do that, I have strange behavior in my application... Like when I submit a form, it is submitted twice...

And I absolutely don't know why...( I really don't know much in RoR )

### Edit

It seems that the question is not clear... The fact is I don't know what to tell you to get some help...

If I take the exemple of my embedded application:

If I add `@import "thredded";` in my application.scss file without setting `config.assets.debug = true` in my environments file. It is not importing the style...
If I do the same with `config.assets.debug = true` in my environments file.

It is working... I would like to understand how to make it works without `config.assets.debug = true`.

Is that a matter of precompile css file or something?

Comment: There's nothing here anyone could use to help.

Comment: What do you need ? I really don't know what information I can give you to make it understandable...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I am under production environement, and I was not doin any:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

After that, my changes are applying just fine (still have my problems with double execution of my JS, but that's something else)...